# I have been asked to use arrays to store and manage objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create a storage system whenever a user gets fuel in their car. The data that needs to be stored is the date, car mileage, number of litres and the cost per litre. a separate class should be created to record these.

I should be able to add in the details of every transaction each time the person gets fuel.

Can anyone help get along the right lines and help me get started? below is my fuel logger class and i do not know how to create the fuel transaction class i was talking about.

```
public class FuelLogger
{
public static void main (String [] arguments)
    {
        FuelTransaction Ft1 = new FuelTransaction("10/01/2016", 500, 10,           0.99);
        FuelTransaction Ft2 = new FuelTransaction("15/01/2016", 560, 10, 0.99);
        FuelTransaction Ft3 = new FuelTransaction();

        Ft3.setDate("24/01/2016");
        Ft3.setCarMileage(670);
        Ft3.setNumberOfLitres(15);
        Ft3.setCostPerLitre(1.01);

        Ft1.displayDetails();
        Ft2.displayDetails();
        Ft3.displayDetails();

        //Amount of fuel bought between 2 dates
        //System.out.println("The total amount of fuel between the two dates  is " + FuelTransaction.getFuelAmount(Ft1, Ft3));

        System.out.println("The total number of FuelTransactions is " + FuelTransaction.getTotalNum());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?
What are you classes, name, properties, ...

Comment: I have to create an array of type fuelTransaction, where fuelTransaction is a class that contains all the information such as the date, car mileage etc. I am just really unsure of how to go about answering this or completing this question.

Comment: So school or interview?

Comment: Post up your existing code to show what you have done so far

Comment: For school, if someone can get me on the right lines that would be great.

Comment: If you want someone to do the code for you go to them and pay them for doing your homework

Comment: Need someone to send me along the right lines not to do the whole thing :) :) :)

Comment: So you want to create a app where a user can enter their amount of fuel on the first purchase and the second one, and the app will calculate the amount? - Im sorry but I dont fully understand your question

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Log object and add detail to the object in constructor and store it.

Comment: How do i do this? I have tried completing a new class for the fuel transaction and it works fine until i have to find the amount of fuel between two dates, so i put in the first line 'public static void betweenTwoDates(String startDate, String endDate, fuelTransaction[] thisFuelTransactions)' but it is saying the symbol cannot be found?

Comment: @Paddy McKenna You have to store last time fuel transaction in vehicle object. So you can calculate now - vehicle.lastFuelTransaction;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class FuelTransaction {

  // Class variables
  String date;
  int mileage, numberOfLitres, costPerLitre;

  // Constructor where we instantiate the FuelTransaction object
  public FuelTransaction(String date, int mileage, int numberOfLitres, int costPerLitre) {

    // Takes all the variables passed in and stores them to the class variable
    this.date = date;
    this.mileage = mileage;
    this.numberOfLitres = numberOfLitres;
    this.costPerLitre = costPerLitre;
  }

  public FuelTransaction() {

    // Empty constructor, sets everything to "" or 0
    this.date = "";
    mileage = numberOfLitres = costPerLitre = 0;
  }

  public void setDate(String date) {

    // Setter to set the date
    this.date = date;
  }

}
```

This isn't the complete class, you'll have to add to it but these are the basics. Notice how there are 2 constructors, this lets you initialize the `FuelTransaction` class by specifying all of the variables like `new FuelTransaction(DATE, MILEAGE, NUMBEROFLITRES, COSTPERLITRE)` but it also lets you call `new FuelTransaction()` and then manually add the data after instantiating with the `setDate()` setter:

```
FuelTransaction ft = new FuelTransaction();
ft.setDate("01-23-45");
```

Comment: Ah yes I got parts of that working just need to work around other bits I've added to get it fully working. Thanks very much!